# Time picker dialog not showing properly in emulator

Tags: android, timepicker

I have a time picker dialog that appears on the click of a button.
Problem:

1. Time Picker on physical device (720 x 1440)
   [image]
2. Time Picker on an emulator(720 x 1280)
   [image]

Code I wrote for timePicker:

```
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.TimePickerTheme,onTimeSetListener,hour,minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

TimePicker theme:

```
<style name="TimePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Which emulator are you using ?

Comment: Google Nexus API23

Comment: Why do you want to change dialog height and width? Can you delete those lines and see if it helps

Comment: ThankYou @DemoDemo worked for me!